# Get monday of the currentweek with linux date

Tags: bash, date

I am writing a bash script and I need the date of the Monday of the current week.

```
date -d monday
```

returns the correct date if it is Monday. And

```
date -d last-monday
```

returns the correct date at Tuesday until Sunday.

I can use an if-clause in the script but I am interested if there is an oneliner too?

Comment: You can write any sequence of statements, including an `if`-clause, in one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
date -d "next-monday - 7 days"

date -d "$(($(date +%u) -1)) days ago"


# today
date  +%Y%m%d
20220524

# Monday
$ date -d "next-monday - 7 days" +%Y%m%d
20220523
# or
$ date -d "$(($(date +%u) -1)) days ago" +%Y%m%d
20220523
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a week starts on Sunday, how about:

```
date -d "$(( 1 - $(date +%w) )) days"
```